# collision detection swift sprite kit.

Tags: swift

I have two obstacles. I am able to drag one (sprite) of them. I would to have the effect that when I drag one obstacle and hit the other one with it, the other one will get affected by the impact and follow the law of physics by wondering off in the other direction.

This is my code so far.

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?
Thanks

```
func addSprite() {
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.size.width / 2)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.35, y: size.height * 0.5)
    sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    sprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(balCategory)
    sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(obstacleCategory)
    sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    sprite.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
    sprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    sprite.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    addChild(sprite)
}
func addObstacle() {
    treat.setScale(0.5)
    treat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: treat.size)
    treat.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    treat.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(obstacleCategory)
    treat.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(balCategory)
    treat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    treat.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    treat.name = "treat"

    treat.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(treat)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is switch `sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0`  and `treat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0` to `sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(obstacleCategory)` for your first function and `treat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(balCategory)`

Setting this value to zero makes it not interact with physics when they collide, let me know if this works.

Comment: It makes it so that when both objects collide they touch each other but can't go through each other anymore. They act like solid blocks now. How can I make it so that the "treat" floats away like in outer space?

Comment: Sorry, missed this error in my answer, set `treat.physicsBody?.dynamic = true` and same for sprite. If dynamic is false it basically means they can't change/move